# javascript error: expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering and hoping someone could help me work out this error I'm getting it says `expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` the thing is the script works but when pasting it in jsfiddle.net I get that error on line `isObserving ? window.obs() : window.dis();` any ideas why and how I could fix this?

```js
(function() {
  var isObserving = false;
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0];

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.info("EVENT TRIGGERT");
    });
  });

  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  };

  window.dis = function() {
    console.log('observer off')
    observer.disconnect();
    ars.innerHTML = "observer off";
  };

  window.obs = function() {
    console.log('observer on')
    observer.observe(target, config);
    ars.innerHTML = "observer on";
  };

  window.toggleObserve = function() {
    isObserving = !isObserving;
    isObserving ? window.obs() : window.dis();
  };
})();

var ars = document.getElementById("ars");
ars.addEventListener("click", toggleObserve);

// simulate change
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>
<button id="ars" style="width: 100%;">observer off</button>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tLejv2b4/ everything works fine

Comment: The code works, it might be that this is rather an eslint issue as you are using a ternary operator where you could (for readability) use an if instead

Comment: You're abusing `?:` by throwing its result away. In that case you should just use `if`/`else` instead. Or factor out the common parts: `window[isObserving ? 'obs' : 'dis']();`